# When does the expectation of a random variable X depend on the order in which its support is listed?

Tags: probability, distributions, expected-value

Reading Blitzstein and Hwang’s introduction to probability http://probabilitybook.net (really good so far!).

On page 150, they mention in regard to the definition of the expectation of a discrete random variable that
The expectation of a discrete random variable X is undefined if the value of the expectation depends on the order in which the support is listed.

I understand that if we the expectation varies depending on said order then we of course don’t have a well-defined expectation(i.e. a single value).

My question(s):

1. What do we mean by the order in which the support is listed?
2. When(some example as well please) does the expectation depend on this ordering?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a [general mathematical result](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/32048/14893) that $\mathbb E[X]$ is only defined when either **(i)** $$\mathbb E[|X|] < \infty$$or **(ii)** $$\mathbb E[|X|] = +\infty$$and one of the expectations $$\mathbb E[\underbrace{X~\mathbb I_{X>0}}_{X^+}]\qquad\mathbb E[\underbrace{X~\mathbb I_{X<0}}_{-X^-}]$$is finite. (Note that $\mathbb E[|X|]=\mathbb E[X~\mathbb I_{X>0}]-\mathbb E[X~\mathbb I_{X<0}]$ since $X=X^+-X^-$ and $|X|=X^++X^-$.)

The remark about the ordering is connected with the [Riemann series theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem). Quoting from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem):

> As an example, the series 1 – 1 + 1/2 – 1/2 + 1/3 – 1/3 + ...
> converges to 0 (for a sufficiently large number of terms, the partial
> sum gets arbitrarily near to 0); but replacing all terms with their
> absolute values gives 1 + 1 + 1/2 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/3 + ... , which sums
> to infinity. Thus the original series is conditionally convergent, and
> can be rearranged (by taking the first two positive terms followed by
> the first negative term, followed by the next two positive terms and
> then the next negative term, etc.) to give a series that converges to
> a different sum: 1 + 1/2 – 1 + 1/3 + 1/4 – 1/2 + ... = ln 2. More
> generally, using this procedure with p positives followed by q
> negatives gives the sum ln(p/q). Other rearrangements give other
> finite sums or do not converge to any sum.